# How to create a tick method that would make sure all blocks are working in accordance with gravity

Tags: java, physics, game-physics

```
   public class Physics {
    private int weight;
    private int durability;
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Level level;
    int tileWidth = Main.WIDTH / 16;
    int tileHeight = Main.HEIGHT / 16;
    
    public Physics(Level level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    private void timer(int time) {//this is a subroutine that creates a slight pause 
        long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();//this is getting the current time in miliseconds
        long target = currTime + time;//this gets the current time and sets the target pause time to the current time plus the time you want to pause for in miliseconds
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < target);//this makes the program idle for the target amount of time
    }

    public void gravity(int weight,int durability, int xPos, int yPos, Tile tile, TileType tileTypes, boolean newblock){//this is the physics subroutine for when you place a block 
        if(tile.getType() == TileType.SKY) {//if the tile you clicked on is a sky tile
            tile.setType(tileTypes, weight, durability);//it sets the new tiles type weight and durability to the ones that were entered dependant on which block the user chose from the pallet
            timer(50);//this is the pause time between the block falling one y coordinate down 
            tile.setType(TileType.SKY, 0, 0);//once the tile is drawn one tile down it changeds the tile above it back to a sky tile 
            yPos++;//this the increases the y possition by one to foxus on the next block down 
            gravity(weight,durability, xPos, yPos, level.tiles[xPos][yPos],tileTypes,true);//this then calls the subroutine within itself and this keeps going until it hits the bottom
        }
        
        //if (newblock == true) {
            if(tile.getType() != TileType.SKY){//once the tile below the tile we're focusing on is not a sky tile this if statement is run  
                Tile tile1 = level.tiles[xPos][yPos-1];//it sets the tile were focusing on to the tile above the non skytile
                tile1.setType(tileTypes, weight, durability);//it then sets this tile to the tile you chose from the pallet 
                weight = tile1.getWeight();
                durability = tile1.getDurability();
                System.out.println(weight+"kg, "+durability);
            }
        //}
        
        //if (newblock == false) {
            
            
            
        //}
    }
    
    public void blockDestruction(Tile tile) {
        
        
        
    }
    
    public void tick(int x, int y) {
        Tile tile = level.tiles[x][y];
        Tile tile1 = level.tiles[x][y-1];
        TileType tilecheck = tile1.getType();
        
        if(tile1.getType() != TileType.SKY && tile1.getType() != TileType.GRASS) {
            gravity(tile.getWeight(),tile.getDurability(),x,y,tile,tile.getType(),false);
            y = y-1;
                    
            /*for (int i = y-1; i>0;i--) {
                if (tilecheck != TileType.SKY) {
                    tile1 = level.tiles[x][i];  
                    tilecheck = tile1.getType();
                }else
                    tile1 = level.tiles[x][i+1];    
                tile1.setType(TileType.SKY);
            }*/
        }
    }   
}
```

the tick method at the end there is what I'm struggling with what im trying to create is a method that i would be able to put inside of my tick method in my main class which will check all blocks to see if there is a block underneath them and if not then it will apply the gravity method to that block. Sorry for the code being such a mess ive been trying loads of solutions and have gotten completely stuck so it is currently a bit of a mess if anything need explaining then please let me know.

[this is what the program looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piVo2.png)

Comment: Beware! Although it is commented out, an else-statement in one of your last lines doesn't have {braces}, which means, `tile1.setType(TileType.SKY);` would be executed in each run of the loop, **not** just when `tilecheck != TileType.SKY` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Yeah that bit of the code was one of the things i was trying out but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean with a tile being underneath another tile? Is that related with the `Level` in any way?

Comment: yes basically the way my program works is the level is created and then you can alter the level by placing your own tiles but the tiles you place are altered by a gravity effect